# Request Parameter is causing SQL Injection with the preparedstatement

Tags: java, sql, spring, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am seeing a a SQL injection

```
SELECT count(id) FROM user  WHERE code= 67 AND user.postal_code like  UPPER('%AL%')
```

I am setting this as a

```
 private int loaddGrantees(Long code, String value)
    {
     DBConnectionManager dBConnectionManager = null;
     Connection conn = null;
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     dBConnectionManager = new DBConnectionManager();
     conn = dBConnectionManager.getConnectionObject(XXX,XXX);
     string sql =  SELECT count(id) FROM user  WHERE code= ? AND user.postal_code LIKE UPPER(?);
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pstmt.setLong(1, code);
      pstmt.setString(2, "%" +value+ "%");
       rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                 number = rs.getInt(1);
             }
     return number;
}
```

From HTTPRequest I see the value is getting from the String value= request.getParameter("Val");

Can I know how to avoid sql injection here for postal_code, I see code parameter is not being retrieved from httpRequest

```
> Vulnerability says:
> 
> /XX/XX/XXX/XX/XX/6769/XX/AL/XX page of the application has been found
> to be vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack in the path parameter
> :value.
> 
> The source code that uses this path parameter in the page is:
> 
> loadGrantees(Person.java:5036)
> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
> 
>     ...   }   ... }
> 
> This code has generated the following query in order to interact with
> the database, using the path parameter value: Note: AL represents the
> value which I am passing in the preparedstatement
> 
> SELECT count(id) FROM user  WHERE code= ? AND user.postal_code LIKE
> UPPER(?); The path parameter searchString in the URL
> /XX/XX/XXX/XX/XX/6769/XX/AL/XX can be modified to contain SQL syntax
> hence changing the query structure, causing unexpected application
> behavior which could lead to information theft, privileges escalation
> and unauthorized actions performed by the attacker.
```

Comment: I have removed it in edits actually there is no single quotes around "?"

Comment: I tried that way its always complaining about requestparams

Comment: `UPPER('?')` is actually a string literal with question mark, so you have only one bund variable in your case. Quotes are not needed because they indicate string literal, but bind variable keeps its type inside it

Comment: yes if I set it as a string as a preparedstatement still why is it causing SQL injection do I need to add anything more while I am setting?

Comment: Please present sufficient code to fully and accurately characterize what you are doing.  At minimum, we need to see specific values for `sql`, `code`, and `value` that reproduce the issue in conjunction with the Java statements presented, and we need to see the basis on which you conclude that injection is occuring.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did some code edits

Comment: Your code is not valid.  Please fix that, though I *think* I see what it is supposed to be.  You still have not shown how you conclude that you are seeing an injection, however.

Comment: Please understand, by the way, that we -- and I feel comfortable speaking for the group on this -- are pretty confident that you are *not* seeing a bona fide code injection through a prepared statement.  I, at least, am looking to understand what is actually happening well enough to explain it to you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Its a lot of code with bits and pieces form different classes thats the reason I am giving an overview, I am trying to do my best explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233293/discussion-between-juke-and-john-bollinger).

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability report seems to be complaining about the possibility that the user-specified `value` parameter contains `%` or `_` characters, which would be interpreted as wildcards rather than literals by the `LIKE` operator.  If that is not intentional then it might indeed afford a malicious user an opportunity to do harm, or at least to  extract data that you did not intend for them to get, but it is not a code injection in the conventional sense. (Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/327/)

If you must form the right-hand operator of a `LIKE` expression from user input (do consider whether you really need that), and you do not intend to allow the user to use the `%` or `_` wildcards in that input *as* wildcards, then you have a few alternatives.  Among those are:

1. Validate the parameter on the server side to ensure that it does not contain any `%` or `_` characters, and reject it if it does.  Ideally, perform client-side validation as well.
2. Munge the `value` parameter to escape any `%` or `_` characters that appear, according to the appropriate syntax for the DBMS you are using.  This is nasty, as it introduces DBMS-dependency and relies on the driver and database not to be clever enough to recognize what you're doing (lest it escape the escapes).  This is the kind of mess that using prepared statements usually avoids.
3. Ensure that the application can safely accommodate users providing values containing wilcards,to be used as wildcards, and tell your vulnerability scanner to stuff it.